# iReports ORA-00911: invalid character

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

When I specify the query via Data-> Report Query I get the below error. It doesn't say what the invalid character is though. Any idea on how to resolve this?

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Can you post the query? What version on JDBC driver are you using? And what version of Oracle do you have?

Comment: Remove one character at a time until you find the invalid one. But seriously... it's really an Oracle question, not an iReport one. Use a tool like SQuirreL SQL or Toad or SQL*Plus to test the query first.

Comment: @mdahlman Removing one character at a time might not work if the invalid character is repeated in the query.

Comment: er... removing one character at a time might from a query not work for a whole bunch of other reasons as well. "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE" would probably fail after removing any one of its characters. But don't worry... I still think I'm hilarious.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem was a semicolon (";") character in the middle of the query. The query ran in oracle SQL developer because the semicolon broke the query at a valid place.

Comment: Thank you, had exactly the same problem.Thought it was a spacing issue,but yeah removing the semi colon did the trick

Comment: Same problem but the semicolon was at the end, and it broke everything